# How to start the date_select in the middle of the years in the filed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the Rails date_select helper.

```
:start_year => Time.now.year

:end_year => 1910
```

I would like the year the user sees when they click to be 1980 which is not the start year or end year.

Is there a way to do this with jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the Date object to the `:default` option.
In your case it's `date_select(:start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => 1910, :default => Date.new(1980) )`

[Docs for the date_select helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select)

Comment: Thanks Kir I tried it even doing :default => {:year => 1980} and :default => Date.new(1980) and it still starts at the start date. Any ideas?